# NullPointerException in LayoutInflater inside the BaseAdapter getView() method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

Here s my getView() method. I am getting null pointer exception while inflating. There are so many answers for the same questions. This is used inside a fragment. But that doesn't suit me.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Context con = null;
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)con.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stores_listview_layout, null);
     }

     TextView tv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
     tv.setText(storeData.get(position).get("merchantName"));

    return vi;
}
```

What is the mistake I am doing here?

Update: This works!

```
         View vi=convertView;
         Context c = null;
         if(convertView==null){
         LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(null);
         vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stores_listview_layout, parent, false);
        }
```

Comment: Context con is never initialized

Comment: instead of con.getApplicationContext(), try to use your Activity's context.

Comment: can you paste your error log please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(null);
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stores_listview_layout, parent, false);
```

Comment: This method is inside a fragment

Comment: storeData.get(position).get("merchantName") can you check what value print on console .Is this correct?

Comment: passed null to the getLayoutInflater() and it worked finally! Thanks buddy

Answer (score 3):

Instead of declaring `Context con;` and then using it - which as pointed out is causing the null pointer exception you can simply use `convertView.getContext()`

Check the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29)

---

Have just actually thought about it and my first thought wouldn't work - Doh!

Since your code is inside a fragment you can access the layoutinflater via [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29)

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if( convertView == null ){
        //you can access layout inflater by accessing hosting activity
        convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stores_listview_layout, parent, false);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
    tv.setText(storeData.get(position).get("merchantName"));
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
con.getApplicationContext()...
```

Here's your fault. `con` hasn't been initialized yet, so it is `null`.
You should use your Activity as a context.

Comment: Then you can call getActivity() for your context.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
Context con;///============> here
View vi=convertView;
if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)con.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stores_listview_layout, null);
....
```

Replace `Context con;` with

```
Context con= getApplicationContext();
```

here in this code you didn't initialize Context variable. try to initialize it first.